# How do use a page on my website to show another page content?

Tags: html

I have some content running on a url say, `xyz.com`

I also have a web app at `abc.com`

I want to present the content of xyz at `xyz.abc.com` OR `abc.com/xyz`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using php you can use this code:

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents("http://example.com");
?>
```

you can also use iframe in html:

```
 <iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```